# Object assigned to property of target view controller in prepareForSegue comes out as a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to set the property of a View Controller I'm segueing to to a custom object (`Restroom`), but it's coming out as a `UITableViewCell`.

Here is code from the origin View Controller that is triggering the segue. The `userDidSelectRestroomNotification` method is called when a user selects a cell in a table view that lists restrooms - the application is then supposed to segue to a View Controller that lists the details of that restroom:

```
- (void)userDidSelectRestroomNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    Restroom *selectedRestroom = (Restroom *)[notification object];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowRestroomDetails" sender:selectedRestroom];
};

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowRestroomDetails"])
    {
        RestroomDetailsViewController *restroomDetailsViewController = 
            (RestroomDetailsViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;

        restroomDetailsViewController.restroom = sender;
    }
}
```

Here is the code in my data source where the notification is posed:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // post a notification when a selection is made
    NSNotification *notification = [NSNotification 
        notificationWithName:RRTableViewDidSelectRestroomNotification 
        object:[self restroomForIndexPath:indexPath]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:notification];
}

- (Restroom *)restroomForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [self.restroomsList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
}
```

Point being, I am sending along a `Restroom` object in my notification.

The issues comes when in the `RestroomDetailsViewController`, I am trying to set the text of a label to the name of the `Restroom` object I'm passing along:

```
@interface RestroomDetailsViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;

@end

@implementation RestroomDetailsViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.nameLabel.text = self.restroom.name;
}

@end
```

It crashes at `self.nameLabel.text = self.restroom.name`. When I inspect the objects, I see that my `self.restroom` object is actually a `UITableViewCell`. What confuses me further is that that `UITableViewCell` appears to be the cell that was selected by the user to trigger the segue -- i.e. the one set up in the data source:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSParameterAssert([indexPath section] == 0);
    NSParameterAssert([indexPath row] < [_restroomsList count]);

    UITableViewCell *restroomCell = [tableView 
        dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:restroomCellReuseIdentifier];

    if(!restroomCell)
    {
        restroomCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
            reuseIdentifier:restroomCellReuseIdentifier];
    }

    restroomCell.textLabel.text = [[_restroomsList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] name];

    return restroomCell;
}
```

I'm not understanding why this happens and how to get that `restroom` property properly assigned to the `Restroom` object.

Comment: Did you connect the segue from the cell or the controller in the storyboard?

Comment: I connected the segue in Storyboard and gave it the ID 'ShowRestroomDetails'

Comment: I asked what you connected it from. Did you connect it directly from the cell, or from the controller?

Comment: i connected it from the controller.

Comment: If you log selectedRestroom in userDidSelectRestroomNotification:, does it give you the right object?

Comment: The other thing I would do, would be to put logs in userDidSelectRestroomNotification:, didSelectRowAtIndexPath, and prepareForSegue to see in what order these methods are called.

Comment: Why are you using postnotification ? i dnt see any requirement here   to use notification.

Comment: A simple function with parameter will do the work.

Comment: @rdelmar logging selectedRestroom does give me the correct object - an instance of Restroom

Comment: @rdelmar you're onto something withthe order the methods are called! its didSelectRowAtIndexPath, prepareForSegue, userDidSelecteRestroomNotification -- when prepareForSegue is called, the sender is a UITableViewCell!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using postnotification ?

I don't see any requirement here to use notification. A simple function with parameter will do the work.

Try Following way to call segue

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowRestroomDetails" sender:[self restroomForIndexPath:indexPath]];
}

- (Restroom *)restroomForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
return [self.restroomsList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
}


 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
      Restroom *selectedRestroom = (Restroom *)sender;


    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowRestroomDetails"])
    {
    RestroomDetailsViewController *restroomDetailsViewController = 
        (RestroomDetailsViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;

    restroomDetailsViewController.restroom = selectedRestroom ;
   }
}
```

Comment: I decided to use notifications when a user selected a cell to notify any controllers interested that a Restroom was selected.

Answer (score 0):

I understand it's not typical to have notifications being posted when cells are pressed - but that's how I'm choosing to implement this application currently.

That being said, here's how I ended up getting this to work (thanks to a comment by @rdelmar saying to check what order the methods are being called in):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowRestroomDetails"])
    {
        if([sender isKindOfClass:[Restroom class]])
        {
            RestroomDetailsViewController *restroomDetailsViewController = (RestroomDetailsViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;

            restroomDetailsViewController.restroom = sender;
        }
    }
}
```

I found that the `prepareForSegue` method was being triggered when a cell was pressed before my `userDidSelectRestroomNotification` method. However, I want `userDidSelectRestroomNotification` to actually be the method that triggers `prepareForSegue` because it creates the needed `Restroom` object. Thus I put a check in my `prepareForSegue` that makes sure the incoming object is a `Restroom` instance.

All that being said - I don't know if this is more of a hack than a solution.

Comment: I don't see how it's possible that prepareForSegue is called before your notification is received in userDidSelectRestroomNotification: since that's where you call performSegue; That says to me that you connected the segue from the cell, not the controller, even though you said otherwise.

Comment: I will re-do the segue and see what happens